# How to solve non-www redirection to www Nginx?

Tags: linux, nginx, redirect

This is my NGinx Web Server configuration

```
    server {
        if ($host ~ ^[^.]+\.betafox\.net$) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
    
    
        if ($host = www.betafox.net) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
    
    
        if ($host = betafox.net) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri; 
        } # managed by Certbot
    
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
    
        #server_name _;
        root /var/www/html;
    
    server_name betafox.net *.betafox.net;
        #return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        location / {
            # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
            proxy_pass  https://betafox.net/;
            proxy_redirect  https://betafox.net/ $host;
            proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
            proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            #fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/etc/alternatives/php-fpm.sock;
     }
    
    
    }
    
    server {
    
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
            listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    
            root /var/www/html;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
    
          # server_name _;
            server_name betafox.net *.betafox.net;
            # Maximum file upload size is 4MB - change accordingly if needed
            client_max_body_size 512M;
            client_body_buffer_size 128k;
            include snippets/letsencrypt-nginx-certs.conf;
            include snippets/letsencrypt-nginx-route.conf;
    
            location / {
                    # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
            }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    
            error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
                    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            }
    
            location ~ \.php$ {
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                    #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php8.0-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/etc/alternatives/php-fpm.sock;
            }
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/betafox.net-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/betafox.net-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    
    }
```

Most part of it was modified automatically by Certbot when I installed SSL Certificates for both my FQDN and Subdomains. The issue I'm facing is about URL redirection. The original URL is [www.betafox.net](http://www.betafox.net), when user types betafox.net is redirected to https://betafoxnet.www.betafox.net/ and there's message that says: The site you were looking for, does not exist.

I only want that all users that type betafox.net are forwaded to [www.betafox.net](http://www.betafox.net). I believe Nginx could do that. How can I achieve such thing?

Comment: remove the fiirst regex part i am really confused that certbot still uses if else instead a basic redirect

Comment: Won't that affect subdomains SSL Cert? I've Wildcard SSL Certificate active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Certbot creates the nginx redirects using `if` with the `$host` variable which is problematic.

It is best to have the redirect in a separate `server` section as follows.

```
# Redirect all requests to betafox.net URLs to corresponding www.betafox.net URLs
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/betafox.net-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/betafox.net-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    server_name betafox.net;

    return 301 https://www.betafox.net$request_uri;
}

# Redirect all other subdomain HTTP requests to HTTPS.
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name *.betafox.net;

    return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;:
}

# Removed the server block for port 80, it looked meaningless

server {
    # Removed the default_server, default_server should not be the actual website
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name betafox.net *.betafox.net;
    # Maximum file upload size is 4MB - change accordingly if needed
    client_max_body_size 512M;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    include snippets/letsencrypt-nginx-certs.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt-nginx-route.conf;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/etc/alternatives/php-fpm.sock;
    }
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/betafox.net-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/betafox.net-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: Well, it works fine though, but there's `nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "betafox.net" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored` warning.

Comment: BTW, something is causing NS_ERROR_REDIRECT_LOOP

Comment: That error is not found in root of site, but in my network admin section. Nginx is returning 302 response code there.

Comment: Sorry... When I renamed my database, I forgot to rename wp_blog's data and that was the cause of many redirects...